# JQuery DatePicker widget showing next, previous png image icons as well as "Next" "Prev" text overlapping those icons

Tags: jquery

Inspite of referencing all the required .js and .css file along with the script tag code required in the .aspx page as below,

```
   <link href="../Styles/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Styles/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Styles/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Styles/jquery.ui.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Scripts/1.7.2.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("txtb_todate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
      });
    </script>
```

The datetime picker is showing the next, previous month's png icon images along with the "Next", "Previous" text written on those images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a custom text for previous and next months, which in your case would be an empty string:

```
$(function () {
    $("txtb_todate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true, 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        prevText: "",
        nextText: ""
    });
});
```

Comment: I already have implemented this workaround, however I wanted to know if there is any other setting present to bypass the text version of "Prev" and "Next" keywords.

Comment: According to the [JQuery UI api documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-nextText) the texts will only be replaced by an icon when using the standard ThemeRoller styling. So in short, I think this is the only clean way of preventing text to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

try `font-size: 0px;` for the respective Next and Previous button's `class`. It will help you to hide the "Next" and "Previous" Texts